# Al convertir mi texto me deja la ultima letra en mayúscula

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de convertir un texto, al momento que lo ingresen en mayuscula o en minuscula , en Capitalice

> TEXTO INGRESADO PRUEBA
>
> 'Texto Ingresado Prueba'
>
> 'texto ingresado prueba'

Estos son los posibles formatos de texto que puedan ingresar

el resultado debería ser

> 'Texto ingresado prueba'

```js
     $('#campoTexto').keyup(function () {
          // string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);

          console.log($(this).val().substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + $(this).val().substr(1).toLowerCase())
          $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + $(this).val().substr(1).toLowerCase());
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="campoTexto" />
```

Este es el codgio que estoy utilizando , pero al momento de mostrar los datos me los muestra de esta forma:

> 'Texto ingresado prueBA'

A veces llega con la ultima letra en mayúscula o con las dos ultimas , Alguien me puede ayudar que salga el texto capitalizado

Comment: validar en onkeyup es costoso, podrias validar al salir del input con el `onfocusout`

Comment: @JackNavaRow por que costoso ?

Comment: vas a estar validando por cada letra que presione, cuando hablo de costoso es a nivel de procesamiento

Comment: Entiendo , pero según la política de mi compañía , tiene que convertir el texto a minúscula mientras se ingresa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes convertir todo a minusculas primero asi:

```js
  $("#boton").click(function(){
   console.log($("#campoTexto").val())
  });



$('#campoTexto').keyup(function () {
      // string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
      $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase());
      $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() +    $(this).val().substr(1));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="campoTexto">
<input type="button" id="boton"  value="Enviar" >
```

Comment: El problema esta al momento de pintarlo no al ingresarlo en el campo serivira igual ?

Comment: Realice la prueba y sigue comportandose igual

Comment: Como puedes ver aqui funciona correctamente

Comment: le puse keydown para realizar la prueba y me estra el texto asi `AaaaaaaA` como si no alcanzara a convertir la ultima letra

Comment: Esta repuesta funciono para mi solo con un cambio en el codigo `.keypress(function ()`   Tenia que cambiar el `keyup` por `keypress`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ir remplazando los elementos con una expresión regular.

```
 $('#campoTexto').keyup(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(.)|\s(.)/g,
      function(txt){ return txt.toUpperCase( ); }
      ));
  });
```

**Explicación de /^(.)|\s(.)/g** 
Son 2 alternativas:

1. **^(.)**  Busca el primer elemento del grupo de palabras.
2. **\s(.)** Busca los espacios en blanco y el elemento que le sigue al espacio en blanco.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu contribución, te sugiero agregar una explicación de lo que realiza el código, revisa [answer], saludos.!

Comment: Gracias lo leeré..